# Sorting based on the count in a related field in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, relational-algebra

I have two models, `Image` and `Tag`. Each Image object can have more than one Tag associated with it, and I want to find my most frequently used tags. How would I go about this? It seems easy enough but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has (only recently) acquired Aggregate support, so now you could do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Tag.objects.annotate(img_count=Count('image')).order_by('img_count')
```

Comment: I think this counts the number of images instead of the number of tags...but I see where you're going.

Comment: This solution very close to yours did the trick:

Tag.objects.annotate(img_count=Count('image')).order_by('img_count')


...Can you please update your answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I have modified my original code, sorry for mixing up the variables :)